# Serial Communication with Verifone vx 520

Tags: c#, serial-port, point-of-sale

I would like to ask a documentation or a guide on how to communicate with Verifone vx 520. I can't find any documentation online regarding this product. I hope you could help me.

My main objective is to send data about the total amount of purchase to Verifone vx520 and then receive some verification that tells if the transaction is successful or not. Thank you very much and I am looking forward to anyone who could help me.

Comment: try [this link](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi_x4mcus3XAhVMRSYKHS7UA8IQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chasepaymentech.com%2Fdocuments%2Fverifone_merchant_manual.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3McS7f1hnAkgbf1WOIL65y)

Comment: or [this one](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwi_x4mcus3XAhVMRSYKHS7UA8IQFgg3MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.telia.fi%2Fdam%2Fjcr%3A97630e32-220c-457c-9dda-0f4b3b10781d%2FMaksupaate_VX520_ohje_A5_Englanti_FINAL_2017_A.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1UkqKQV0b6Z4idC0DHutJx)

Comment: other wise here is an old [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30024304/5174469) to this topic

Comment: Thanks but there is no communication protocol in the link you provided. I still have no idea of what type of message I should send to the bank card machine and if there is a response, I don't know how to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the Firmware/Software running on the Vx520.  You have to contact your vendor to get such information.  There are many different protocols to talk to card terminals, e.g. ZVT, OPI, VEZ etc.

Vx520 is "only" the hardware platform, used by many companies, implementing their own software and protocols.